# Why does gradle build add "-1" to the end of my bundle id?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Recently updated my `Android SDK Build-tools` and now none of my project are successfully building to device.

It builds and deploys to device successfully, although it can't start the activity due to the build tools adding a `-1` to the bundle id:

`12-22 13:15:08.346  5547  5547 W System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gethuman.android/com.tns.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.tns.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gethuman.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gethuman.android-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.gethuman.android-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Notice the `-1` added to the DexPathList `/data/app/com.gethuman.android-1/base.apk`.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing to "resolve". That is the path where Android installed your app.

Comment: Yes but before, the `-1` was never added.

Comment: And your proof of this is... what, exactly? The build tools do not determine the directory name that Android, the OS, uses for installing your app.

Comment: In terms of your actual problem (`Didn't find class...`), try a full uninstall of your app, clean the project, then rebuild and reinstall it.

Comment: @CommonsWare omgerd that fixed it :O
I was using `adb uninstall com.gethuman.android` to uninstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing data and uninstalling resolved. Thank you!